# Does LINQ Enumerable query return copy or reference?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to replicate the `Skip` and `Take` from C# in C++ in order to create slices. Something like:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = { 59, 82, 70, 56, 92, 98, 85 };

auto slice = grades.skip(3).take(2); // {56, 92}
```

After checking how slices work in [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Golang](https://golangbot.com/arrays-and-slices/), I basically understand that they preferred shadow copy over deep copy. I understand the trade off between allocating new memory but having independent data and having related data by copying only the reference.

Now, I also checked [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Skip__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Take__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_) but I can't find which one they use.

In short, do they return some kind of Enumerator at the start and at the end? Or do they create an entirely new IEnumerable?

### Edit

So, I didn't know we can access the source code (mentioned in the comments). And apparently it returns an iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count) {
   if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      return SkipIterator<TSource>(source, count);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`Skip` sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e,references). It returns new enumerable with items from the original collection. The same is true for `Take`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip, Take and other method of LINQ does not return any collection. They return `IEnumerable` interface that allows to get next element from underlying source.
This is concept of lazy loading. `Skip` and `Take` does not actualy filter your collection untill you need the result.

You can copy all elements from IEnumerable to some collection with method `ToArray` or `ToList`.

Artile for reference: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/10/01/lazy-linq-and-enumerable-objects.aspx

Comment: I noticed that in the MoreLINQ code yes. So this object is the same as the one in the original IEnumerable, right ? and then you can copy with the two functions you mentionned.

Answer (score 4):

Linq returns new references only for base types (int, string, double ecc..). The IEnumerable will be same instance of initial list, you have to call ToList o ToArray to create new collection.

Comment: what about complex types ?

Comment: C# doesn't clone complex types unless you do it by yourself. You've to implement a clone method for your classes and call it inside Select method of Linq.